# Symfony2 form type nested too many queries

Tags: forms, symfony, types, entity

I am developing a webshop system and currently I am working at the admin tools. I've got 4 related entities

- Articles

  - stores main article data (name, description)
- ArticleSuppliers

  - stores variants data (articleNumber, price..)
- ArticleAttributesValues

  - stores attributes for each variant (value e.g. red, 40cm)
- ArticleAttributes

  - stores names of attributes (color, height...)

Since it's much easier to edit a product, I would like to merge the forms together which is working.

**ArticlesType** binds **ArticleSuppliersType** binds **ArticleAttributesValuesType**

My FormType: **ArticleAttributesValues** contains an entity choice  of **ArticleAttributes**

This is working! But there is a huge problem. I display each variant with their attributes so there is a query for each attribute (imagine a product with 20 variants and 10 attributes).

The solution would be easy: I just need to give an array of attributeNames + id to my FormType, but I do not know how this is done.

I would be grateful for every other solution though.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I will try to explain my problem with code:

```
// controller
$article = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Articles')->find($id);

$form = $this->createForm(new ArticleType(), $article);
```

This is my article type:

```
    // articleType
    $builder->add('shortName', 'text', 
                array('label' => false))
            ->add('shortDescription', 'text', 
                array('label' => false))
            ->add('longDescription', 'textarea', 
                array('label' => false))
            ->add('variants', 'collection', array('type' => new VariantsType()))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));
```

This relates to VariantsType:

```
    // variantsType
    $builder->add('supplierArticleNumber', 'text', 
                array('label' => false))
            ->add('price', 'text', 
                array('label' => false))
            ->add('variantvalues', 'collection', array('type' => new VariantsvaluesType()));
```

This relates to VariantsvaluesType, where my **choice field** is.

```
    // variantsvaluesType
    $builder->add('attributeValue', 'text', 
                array('label' => false))
            ->add('attributeUnit', 'text', 
                array('label' => false, 'required' => false))
            ->add('attrName', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MyBundle:ArticleAttributes',
                'property' => 'attributeName',
            ));
```

This choice field is the same (of course there are changes sometimes), so it would be unnecessary to query it X-times...

My idea was to load all attributeNames in my controller and pass it via **$options** to **variantsvaluesType**, but this is not working...

Comment: do you want o pass an array to the form type is that it?

Comment: @dheeraj Yes, but is not the first level form type. I have to pass it to a nested form type of another nested form type

Comment: I'm probably not understanding the question.  Are the queries themselves slowing things up because of lazy loading?  If so then make yourself a custom query and join the various entities that you know will need.

Comment: @Cerad Your comment made me think, I discovered the query return 2000 result FOR EACH select. Maybe that's the problem for a bad performance, but still. I do not want 300 queries for a single view

Comment: Still have no idea what you are actually asking about.  It sounds like your form has thousands of elements?  It will be slow no matter what you do.  And if you don't want 300 queries then don't make 300 queries.  It also seems like you think the problem can be solved by passing an array of something to something.  If so then pass the data via the options parameter or make the form type a service and inject the data.

Comment: Please see my EDIT above

Comment: Instead of `$em->getRepository('MyBundle:Articles')->find($id);` can't you create a custom repository function that joins all of the related entities and return that for your `$article` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I see, well maybe you can try the next idea. Create a service with a get function for each collection to load, then in the constructor of the service you can load all the list only one time. Then  you can use that service wherever you needed. It must work like a singleton. The inconvenience is that all those list should be loaded all the time in memory, but nothing is for free. Will be something like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class CollectionsService
{
    private $em;

    private $collectionOne;

    private $collectionTwo;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->collectionOne= $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:CollectionOne')->findAll();
        $this->collectionTwo= $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:CollectionTwo')->findAll();
    }

    public function getCollectionOne(){
         return $this->collectionOne;
    }

    public function getCollectionTwo(){
         return $this->collectionTwo;
    }

}
```

Also must work something  in the functions like next one , and don't be necessary do the load in the constructor.

```
public function getCollectionOne(){
    if($this->collectionOne == null){
       $this->collectionOne= $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:CollectionOne')->findAll();
    }
    return $this->collectionOne;
}
```

Then expose the class as a service in services.yml

```
parameters:
     collection.controller: AppBundle\Services\CollectionsService

services:
     collections.service:
             class: "%collection.controller%"
             arguments:
                     entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

And finally just use the service in the controller or the form to update the data `$options['data']`.

```
$collectionOne = $this->get('collections.service')->getCollectionOne();
```

I hope this help you.